# How to handle TokenMismatchException when session expires on the client side in Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel + ajax for in my project, and this token_mismatch exception is giving me a serious headache.

**The Problem**
CSRF Token expires, when user session expires, and then returns a execption or rather error. This error happens when a user leave's the page after some time, specifically after 120M, then try to send a request, i get this token mismatch exception, because the use session token has expired, and the browser is sending an old one.

**My approach - if possible**
i caught the session expired in my Exception/handler and then generated a new one and then replaced it with the old one and send the request again, however this is not working because the session token needs to be refreshed from the back-end as well, please i need help on this thank you.

```
  var form_data = new FormData();
      form_data.append('_token', '{{csrf_token()}}');
      form_data.append('username', $('input[name="username"]').val());
      form_data.append('password', $('input[name="password"]').val());

      axios.post('/sign-in', form_data )
      .then(function(resp){
           console.log(resp.data.data);
       })
       .catch(function(error){
           printErrorMsg(error.response.data.error);
        })
      });
```

In my expection code

```
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
   if ($request->ajax()) {
       return response([
       'error' => ['expired' => ['token expired']]], 422);
    }
}
```

So my question is: is there any way to refresh the session token without leaving the page ? perhaps replacing it or something.

Comment: how did you reach the conclusion of ```120s```?

Comment: It's 120 minutes. If that is still not enough, you could take a look at [Laravel Caffeine](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine)

Comment: hey, sorry it was a typo error, i taught u should have known, edidtted it

Comment: @Mozammil Laravel caffeine doesnt work for ajax request.